# Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined knuthShuffle

Tags: jquery, random

I have a variable with images and I want to randomize the order of the images. I try to do this using https://github.com/coolaj86/knuth-shuffle. But when I use this code I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: images is not defined "

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var images = [
    'dali.jpg',
    'illusionisme.png',
    'impresionisme.jpg',
    'popart.jpg',
    'abstracter.jpg',
    'abstrat.jpg',
    'concept.jpg',
    'fingerpaint.jpg',
    'flowers.jpg',
    'graffiti.jpg',
    'groovy.jpg',
    'skelly.jpg',
    'vangogh.jpg'
    ]
    , b
    ;

  // The shuffle modifies the original array
  // calling a.slice(0) creates a copy, which is assigned to b
  b = window.knuthShuffle(images.slice(0));
  console.log(b);
}());
```

I use this code to pull random images from the variable.

```
$(".art").each(function(){
    $(this).prepend('<img src="assets/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that the images variable is not in the window object but in your closure. As a quick fix (not recommended) try to expose the images variable to the window object.

```
var images = [
    'dali.jpg',
    'illusionisme.png',
    'impresionisme.jpg',
    'popart.jpg',
    'abstracter.jpg',
    'abstrat.jpg',
    'concept.jpg',
    'fingerpaint.jpg',
    'flowers.jpg',
    'graffiti.jpg',
    'groovy.jpg',
    'skelly.jpg',
    'vangogh.jpg'
    ]
    , b
    ;
    window.images = images;
```

Comment: Yup, when I put my code inside the variable function I don't get the error. Any idea why it doesn't work the other way?

Comment: You should read about the JavaScript execution context (http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) and self invoking functions (http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/). Basivally your function executes itself right after being parsed and then encapsulates all the content inside in a closure. Therefore, the images variable is not accessible from outside the closure.